# is there any way to train spacy on google colab gpu?

Tags: google-colaboratory, spacy

I want to train spacy model on custom dataset but its take too much time  for training, is there any way to speed up the training.
I passed device=0 in ner.begin_training() but it takes same amount of time as before.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Go to `[EDIT]` -> `[Notebook settings]` -> Select *GPU* under `Hardware Acceleration` (It restarts the runtime, so all your cell states get lost)
2. Use `!pip install -U spacy[cuda100]` to install spacy with Cuda Support
3. Run the following

Script:

```
import spacy
gpu = spacy.prefer_gpu()
print('GPU:', gpu)
```

It returns:

```
GPU: True
```

Comment: Google Colab has now Cuda 10.1, per "!nvcc --version". Then you should do "!pip install -U spacy[cuda101]"